# Communication from plugin to android and android to plugin

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

im trying to send a push notification from chrome plugin using javascript to android device. so when user login using the plugin, they will be authenticated using Firebase Authentication. then a approval notification should be sent to their android device. after clicking "approve" a list of password will be displayed in the plugin

I tried using Firebase Cloud Messaging. From the console, I tried testing it using the device token and the notification indeed went through. But im not sure how to send it from the plugin to the android device, and send the password back from android app to the plugin

Comment: There is no way to send a message directly from one device to another device through Firebase Cloud Messaging. There *is* an API, but that can only be used from trusted environments.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, what can I do to achieve this? I am very new to android and firebase. can you please suggest how I can achieve that functionality?

Comment: I linked a few questions that cover the same topic, each of which has multiple links to even more information. I recommend checking those out to learn more.